# Can site.com attach (and access) identifying cookies to TorBrowser session if JavaScript disabled?

Tags: javascript, noscript, cookies

Can site.com attach (and access) identifying cookies to TorBrowser session if JavaScript disabled?

I request "New Identity" and disable all JavaScript using TBB's NoScript in top-left of browser. I then visit news.com and read an article but news.com wants to identify my TBB session and tries to attach a cookie. I then visit food.com and look at recipe but food.com asks TBB session for all cookies (or maybe only cookie.data.com that by coincidence is same cookie company as used by news.com).

With JavaScript disabled and use of TBB alone,

- can news.com attach a cookie to my TBB session?
- can food.com access a previously attached cookie from my TBB session?
- can data.com connect news story X to recipe Y based on attached cookies from first two steps?

With JavaScript **enabled** and use of TBB alone,

- can news.com attach a cookie to my TBB session?
- can food.com access a previously attached cookie from my TBB session?
- can data.com connect news story X to recipe Y based on attached cookies from first two steps?

Answer (score 1):

#### With or without Javascript

Tor Browser has a default policy of blocking third party cookies. Cookies can only be set or retrieved by request of domain in the URL bar, regardless of resource fetches from third party websites.

1. "can news.com attach a cookie to my TBB session?"

   - Yes. Cookies are an extension of the HTTP protocol. They do not require active script content on the page to function. Infact in many cases they are intentionally taken out of reach of javascript through the `HttpOnly` tag that can be included when they're initially set, meaning these cookies cannot be accessed directly by javascript.
2. "can food.com access a previously attached cookie from my TBB session?"

   - Yes. Assuming the cookie hasn't expired (they have an expire date that's decided when they're first set) and you're using the same session (I.E. you haven't used New Identity) you will resend the cookies with every HTTP request.
3. "can data.com connect news story X to recipe Y based on attached cookies from first two steps?"

   - No. Cookies are bound to a hostname (and optionally a path on the hostname). news.com can set, and will be resupplied previously set, cookies for news.com, it will never see or set cookies for food.com or data.com. This is obvious when you consider the usage of cookies as a means of authentication, if evil.com could access cookies for bank.com then evil.com could use those to steal your login session and try to masquerade as you with bank.com.

So...with a fresh identity and javascript disabled, you visit news.com. news.com tries to set a cookie, it is successful. data.com (I am assuming this is what you're asking about) has some content embedded in news.com. data.com tries to set a cookie for data.com through news.com, it fails because it is a third party it also does not receive any previously set cookies for data.com because it is a third party and it cannot see the cookies for news.com for the same reason. food.com is the same. Furthermore, food.com and news.com both used distinct circuits because tor browser isolates circuits based on the first party domain. data.com cannot link food.com to news.com or any of them between each other *assuming they only use cookies*.

#### However...

Cookies are a long established, well studied, and *overt* session tracking mechanism. There are plenty of *covert* ways to use other mechanisms in browsers for tracking users and the simple scenario presented in the question doesn't reflect a realistic <del>adversary</del>advertiser.

<del>With javascript enabled and a script controlled (or at least written) by data.com embedded on both food.com and news.com, it turns out it's possible for it to link these, thanks to [`XMLHTTPRequest.withCredentials = true;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)</del>Correction: I created a test for this *(because `withCredentials` seemed insane)* by trying to use javascript to set and retrieve a cookie from a third party domain using this, it seems that the cookies policy overrules this and denies the third party setting or getting it.

There are ways news.com, data.com and food.com could collude to do this *without* javascript *or* cookies. I'm not going to try to exhaustively enumerate them here, that's left as an exercise for the reader. For the curious, there is a good overview of them in [this document](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/client-identification-mechanisms) from the Chrome security team.

If you do not want to have your browsing on news.com, food.com, and data.com linked together *use New Identity*, that's what it's there for!

*Updated to include `XMLHTTPRequest.withCredentials`*

*Updated to **correct** `XMLHTTPRequest.withCredentials`*

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this has anything to do with javascript (or Tor).

Cookies are only sent back to the site that set them. They only know about other sites you visit if the sites 'work together' (are owned by the same party, share data, let each other put iframes in their pages, ... ).

This is regardless of whether you use Tor or not.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can be used without any scripting on the client side at all! They're different than JS functionality of your endpoint. So the answer is **Yes**, they can be used on a server side, and **No** client-side processing will be possible if you're disabling scripts in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible even without **any** active content on a page, see [Cookie RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) - it's a standard about cookies and Set-Cookie headers