# Does Tor address the excessivity of cookies websites post on the browser?

Tags: security

I have not found anything anywhere that addresses the excessivity of cookies, including Third Party cookies, that are presently being posted by websites into connecting browsers. This is primarily related to the tracking cookies that websites, both parties, are presently adding to any computer that connects them.

Does Tor address this issue?

Comment: You are aware that you wouldn't be able to post this question without cookies, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Tor Browser disables [Third Party Cookies](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#identifier-linkability):

> The Cross-Origin Identifier Unlinkability design requirement is satisfied through first party isolation of all browser identifier sources. First party isolation means that all identifier sources and browser state are scoped (isolated) using the URL bar domain. This scoping is performed in combination with any additional third party scope. When first party isolation is used with explicit identifier storage that already has a constrained third party scope (such as cookies and DOM storage), this approach is referred to as "double-keying".

It also provides the New Identity feature, which when used will remove all cookies from the session. Cookies also do not persist between sessions, as such you can use this to unlink your browsing.

Also cookies are entirely unrelated to any "virus".

Related questions:

[Why does not Tor Browser disable cookies completly?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12491/why-does-not-tor-browser-disable-cookies-completly)

[Can site.com attach (and access) identifying cookies to TorBrowser session if JavaScript disabled?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8806/can-site-com-attach-and-access-identifying-cookies-to-torbrowser-session-if-ja/12346#12346)

Answer (score 0):

Tor itself works on OSI layers 3 and 4(in particular), so the answer is NO.

If you're about a Tor Browser - some things were made to mitigate the risks, but not in a full scale. Erase the caches if you need to wipe out all the cookies, that's the only secure way